# How to improve function with all-to-all rows computation within a groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time

Say I have this simple dataframe-

```
dic = {'firstname':['Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve','Steve'],
       'lastname':['Johnson','Johnson','Johnson','Johnson','Johnson',
                   'Johnson'],
       'company':['CHP','CHP','CHP','CHP','CHP','CHP'],
       'faveday':['2020-07-13','2020-07-20','2020-07-16','2020-10-14',
                  '2020-10-28','2020-10-21'],
       'paid':[200,300,550,100,900,650]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df['faveday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['faveday'])
print(df)
```

with output-

```
  firstname lastname company    faveday  paid
0     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-13   200
1     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-20   300
2     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-16   550
3     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-10-14   100
4     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-10-28   900
5     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-10-21   650
```

I want to be able to keep the rows that have a faveday within 7 days of another, but also their paid columns have to sum greater than 1000.

Individually, if I wanted to apply the 7 day function, I would use-

```
def sefd (x): 
    return np.sum((np.abs(x.values-x.values[:,None])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))<=7,axis=1)>=2
s=df.groupby(['firstname', 'lastname', 'company'])['faveday'].transform(sefd)
df['seven_days']=s
df = df[s]
del df['seven_days']
```

This would keep all of the entries (All of these are within 7 days of another faveday grouped by firstname, lastname, and company).

If I wanted to apply a function that keeps rows for the same person with the same company and a summed paid amount > 1000, I would use-

```
df = df[df.groupby(['lastname', 'firstname','company'])['paid'].transform(sum) > 1000]
```

Just a simple transform(sum) function

This would also keep all of the entries (since all are under the same name and company and sum to greater than 1000).

However, if we were to combine these two functions at the same time, one row actually would not be included.

My desired output is-

```
  firstname lastname company    faveday  paid
0     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-13   200
1     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-20   300
2     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-07-16   550
4     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-10-28   900
5     Steve  Johnson     CHP 2020-10-21   650
```

Notice how index 3 is no longer valid because it's only within 7 days of index 5, but if you were to sum index 3 paid and index 5 paid, it would only be 750 (<1000).

It is also important to note that since indexes 0, 1, and 2 are all within 7 days of each other, that counts as one summed group (200 + 300 + 550 > 1000).

The logic is that I would want to first see (based on a group of firstname, lastname, and company name) whether or not a faveday is within 7 days of another. Then after confirming this, see if the paid column for these favedays sums to over 1000. If so, keep those indexes in the dataframe. Otherwise, do not.

A suggested answer given to me was-

```
df=df.sort_values(["firstname","lastname","company","faveday"])

def date_difference_from(x,df):
    return abs((df.faveday - x).dt.days)

def grouped_dates(grouped_df):
    keep = []
    for idx, row in grouped_df.iterrows():
        within_7 = date_difference_from(row.faveday,grouped_df) <= 7
        keep.append(within_7.sum() > 1 and grouped_df[within_7].paid.sum() > 1000)
    msk = np.array(keep)
    
    return grouped_df[msk]

df = df.groupby(["firstname","lastname","company"]).apply(grouped_dates).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

This works perfectly for small data sets like this one, but when I apply it to a bigger dataset (10,000+ rows), some inconsistencies appear.

Is there any way to improve this code?

Comment: What do you do with the case of 3 dates, each 4 days apart (e.g. 01-01 $500, 01-05 $500, 01-09 $500)? should the middle date group both to the left and right? both for date count and paid sum?

Comment: If possible, yes include all 3. The overlap would be important because it's within that 7 day window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that avoids looping idx to compare if other rows are within 7 days, but involves `unstack` and `reindex` so it will increase memory usage (I tried tapping into the `_get_window_bounds` method of rolling but it proved above my expertise). It should be fine for the scale you request. Although this solution's is on par of yours with the toy df you provided, it is orders of magnitude faster on larger datasets.

***Edit: allow multiple deposits in one date.***

Take this data (with `replace=True` by default in random.choice)

```
import string
np.random.seed(123)
n = 40
df = pd.DataFrame([[a, b, b, faveday, paid]
    for a in string.ascii_lowercase
    for b in string.ascii_lowercase
    for faveday, paid in zip(
        np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'), n),
        np.random.randint(100, 1200, n))
    ], columns=['firstname', 'lastname', 'company', 'faveday', 'paid'])
df['faveday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['faveday'])
df = df.sort_values(["firstname", "lastname", "company", "faveday"]).reset_index(drop=True)

>>>print(df)
      firstname lastname company    faveday  paid
0             a        a       a 2020-01-03  1180
1             a        a       a 2020-01-18   206
2             a        a       a 2020-02-02   490
3             a        a       a 2020-02-09   615
4             a        a       a 2020-02-17   471
...         ...      ...     ...        ...   ...
27035         z        z       z 2020-11-22   173
27036         z        z       z 2020-12-22   863
27037         z        z       z 2020-12-23   675
27038         z        z       z 2020-12-26  1165
27039         z        z       z 2020-12-30   683

[27040 rows x 5 columns]
```

And the code

```
def get_valid(df, window_size=7, paid_gt=1000, groupbycols=['firstname', 'lastname', 'company']):
    # df_clean = df.set_index(['faveday'] + groupbycols).unstack(groupbycols)
        # # unstack names to bypass groupby
    df_clean = df.groupby(['faveday'] + groupbycols).paid.agg(['size', sum])
    df_clean.columns = ['ct', 'paid']
    df_clean = df_clean.unstack(groupbycols)
    df_clean = df_clean.reindex(pd.date_range(df_clean.index.min(),
        df_clean.index.max())).sort_index() # include all dates, to treat index as integer
    window = df_clean.fillna(0).rolling(window_size + 1).sum()
        # notice fillna to prevent false NaNs while summing
    df_clean = df_clean.paid * ( # multiply times a mask for both conditions
        (window.ct > 1) & (window.paid > paid_gt)
        ).replace(False, np.nan).bfill(limit=7)
        # replacing with np.nan so we can backfill to include all dates in window
    df_clean = df_clean.rename_axis('faveday').stack(groupbycols)\
        .reset_index(level='faveday').sort_index().reset_index()
        # reshaping to original format
    return df_clean

df1 = get_valid(df, window_size=7, paid_gt=1000,
    groupbycols=['firstname', 'lastname', 'company'])
```

Still running at 1.5 seconds (vs 143 seconds of your current code) and returns

```
      firstname lastname company    faveday       0
0             a        a       a 2020-02-02   490.0
1             a        a       a 2020-02-09   615.0
2             a        a       a 2020-02-17  1232.0
3             a        a       a 2020-03-09   630.0
4             a        a       a 2020-03-14   820.0
...         ...      ...     ...        ...     ...
17561         z        z       z 2020-11-12   204.0
17562         z        z       z 2020-12-22   863.0
17563         z        z       z 2020-12-23   675.0
17564         z        z       z 2020-12-26  1165.0
17565         z        z       z 2020-12-30   683.0

[17566 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: So, with the new edits, there are a couple issues. As previously stated in my question, I would like to keep all the entries that make up the >1000 limit (like the transform function I mentioned). If two entries are on the same date, it combines both rows into one (which would not be beneficial). The other issue is that if you introduce other columns into the dataframe, the edit only keeps firstname, lastname, company, paid, and faveday and gets rid of any other column. Is there a way to solve these issues?

Comment: I see the point of merging all rows of the same date... about keeping any other columns, again, there's no mention in the original question... the first thing that comes to mind is to filter the original df using the output of this function, by setting `groupbycols + ['faveday']` as index on both dfs and filter `df.loc[df.index.isin(df_clean.index), :]` ... I'll come back to you if a better solution comes to mind

Comment: You do understand that this site is for questions about a specific problem with your code... but you are essentially using it as a code factory, in future posts please take the time to fully explain your problem with all caveats, it's the least you can do if you expect other people you help you out for free